# Check if viewed source not render

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way to check if the current request was for page source (HTML) not actual site?

And if not (which I think is the case), is there a way I could somehow "parse" this out of request parameters and maybe times or something?

I need this to display real source when viewing it, and trimmed one when rendering it..

Comment: What is the intent?  Is there content on the page that you are trying to protect?

Comment: what you mean by "Current request was for Page source (HTML) not acutal site ?

Comment: @Phoenix, less data requested when rendering. [at]Shyju, well, if current request didn't end up in a rendered page, but source code only.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to check if the current request was for page source (HTML) not actual site?

No. The request is always for the page source. There is no way to distinguish what the browser is going to do with it.

Also, many browsers (like IE) can't make a request for "view source" at all - you always load the whole site, render it, and then do a "view source".

Workaround ideas: (All terribly flawed)

- Add some JavaScript to the page making an Ajax call. If the call is made, the page was rendered.
- Add some image resource to the page. If it's loaded, the page was rendered.

If this is to protect your HTML source code, forget it and go do something productive instead. :)

Comment: Oh, the "some image resource" idea looks like a great way to do it. What are the flaws you see for it?

Comment: @Tom mainly that it's not 100% reliable (the user agent could have images turned off) and secondly, the information is not available at the time of loading the page, so you can't react to the information straight away.

Comment: I guess I'll have to do some nasty experiments with it. I'll keep this unanswered until I have done the experiments.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting to send optimized/compressed/bandwidth-friendly code when it's being viewed in the browser, and readable/understandable/indented code if the user is wanting to view the source code, right?

Unfortunately, that's not possible, and I suspect it would be counter-productive, since it would prevent you from debugging problems if your Javascript minimizer or HTML compressor code was introducing problems. It would be far better to use something that reintroduces whitespace and indentation for readability. For example, the [View Source Chart](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/view-source-chart/) extension for Firefox. (I don't know what options there are for unminimizing Javascript code.)

Comment: As for the question, yes, that's the idea. As for the answer, debugging is debugging, all compressors/minimizers are turned off then.

Comment: @Tom Would you ever need/want to view the uncompressed source in a production environment?  What about just keeping the code unminimized in development and minimizing the code in production (e.g., as part of the deploy process).

Comment: Not me, but others would, and more than once.